# Table not displaying under tab-Jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using a jquery to display the app, java versions of Production and the lower environment in a tabbed manner.
The version details will be displayed in the table we should be able to view the versions in each tab.Unfortunately, it is not coming as the results get appended in the first tab itself.

```
fn_tab()
{
echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang = "en"> <head><meta charset = "utf-8">'
echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">'
echo '<img src="http://www.bridge2solutions.com/wp-content/themes/bones-v1.06/library/images/logo2-b2s.jpg" width="225" height="78">'>>$WEB_DIR/AppleVersion.html
echo '<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">'>>$WEB_DIR/AppleVersion.html
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">'>>$WEB_DIR/AppleVersion.html
echo '<link type="text/css"  href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css rel="stylesheet">'>>$WEB_DIR/AppleVersion.html
echo  '<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>'>>$WEB_DIR/AppleVersion.html
echo  '<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>'>>$WEB_DIR/AppleVersion.html
   echo '   <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
         });
      </script>'>>$WEB_DIR/AppVersion.html
 echo '    <style>
         #tabs-1{font-size: 14px;}
         .ui-widget-header {
            background:#b9cd6d;
            border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
         }
      </style>'>>$WEB_DIR/AppVersion.html


echo ' </head>'
echo ' <body>
      <div id = "tabs">
         <ul>
            <li><a href = "#tabs-1">PRODUCTION</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#tabs-2">BREAKFIX</a></li>
         </ul>
<div id = "tabs-1">
        <table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th class='titulo'>Components</td>
        <th class='titulo'>App Version</td>
        <th class='titulo'>Java Version</td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr><td>Webapp server</td><td>'${arr[0]}'</td><td>'${jarr[0]}'</td>
        <tr></tr><td>Admin server</td><td>'${arr[1]}'</td><td>'${jarr[1]}'</td>
        <tr></tr><td>Image Server</td><td>'1.3.43-171'</td><td>'1.8.0_51'</td>
        <tr></tr><td>Product Service</td><td>'${arr[2]}'</td><td>'${jarr[2]}'</td>
        <tr></tr><td>Order service</td><td>'${arr[3]}'</td><td>'${jarr[3]}'</td>

        </div>
        <div id = "tabs-2">

        <table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th class='titulo'>Components</td>
        <th class='titulo'>App Version</td>
        <th class='titulo'>Java Version</td>

        </tr>
        <tr></tr><td>Webapp server</td><td>'${arr[0]}'</td><td>'${jarr[0]}'</td>
        <tr></tr><td>Admin server</td><td>'${arr[1]}'</td><td>'${jarr[1]}'</td>
        <tr></tr><td>Images Server</td><td>'1.3.43-171'</td><td>'1.8.0_51'</td>
        <tr></tr><td>Product Service</td><td>'${arr[2]}'</td><td>'${jarr[2]}'</td>
        <tr></tr><td>Order service</td><td>'${arr[3]}'</td><td>'${jarr[3]}'</td>
                </div>    
      </div>

 </body>'>> $WEB_DIR/Version.html

echo '</html>'
}

fn_tab
```

What went wrong in the above code?

Comment: <tr></tr><td>Webapp server</td><td>'${arr[0]}'</td><td>'${jarr[0]}'</td>. Close </tr> after <td> is added.   <tr><td>Webapp server</td><td>'${arr[0]}'</td><td>'${jarr[0]}'</td></tr>

Comment: didnt get you, are you asking me to close with <tr> tag after </td>
is it something with onclick function

Comment: No. you closing <tr></tr> tag before adding <td></td> tags.